# c# утечка памяти (Найдена утечка как устранить)

Tags: c#

<strike>В проекте использую сторонние dll. Подозреваю, что утечка там, есть у меня еще одно узкое место</strike>

Значит так.

1. Создаю поток
2. В созданном потоке

   2.1 Создаю System.Windows.Window

   2.2 Разворачиваю на весь экран (беру размеры экрана и выставляю их в размер окна)

   2.3 Делаю стиль None и полупрозрачность

   2.4 Создаю таймер, запускаю и вызываю у окна ShowDialog()

   2.4 Приходит час "х" и я делаю close окна в таймере

Вот тут основная проблемма, если перез "сдыханием" потока я не делаю

```
      win.Hide();
      win.Opacity = 1;
      win.Width = 1;
      win.Height = 1;
      win.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
      win.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
      win.Topmost = false;
```

то бешено копится память, не пойму почему окно не удаляет себя из памяти...

Ниже представлен код класса

```
public class WaitWindows
{
  protected WaitWindows() : base() { }
  protected object m_StopLock = new object();
  protected object m_TextLock = new object();
  protected string m_Text = "";
  protected bool m_IsStop = false;
  public string TextMessage
  {
    get
    {
      string r = "";
      lock (m_TextLock)
        r = m_Text;
      return r;
    }
    set
    {
      lock (m_TextLock)
      {
        m_Text = value;
      }
    }
  }
  public void Stop()
  {
    lock (m_StopLock) m_IsStop = true;
  }
  public bool IsStop
  {
    get
    {
      bool b;
      lock (m_StopLock) b = m_IsStop;
      return b;
    }
  }
  public static WaitWindows Create(bool isStopButton = false, int timeout = 1000)
  {
    WaitWindows w = new WaitWindows();
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(w.ClientsThread));
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
    t.Start();
    return w;
  }

  protected void ClientsThread()
  {
    if (IsStop) return;
    TextBlock text = new TextBlock()
    {
      FontSize = 60,
      FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
      VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
      HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
      Text = TextMessage,
      TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
    };
    Border border = new Border() { Background = Brushes.White, Child = text };
    System.Drawing.Rectangle screenResolution = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    Window win = new Window()
    {
      AllowsTransparency = true,
      Opacity = 0.8,
      Content = border,
      Left = screenResolution.Left,
      Top = screenResolution.Top,
      Width = screenResolution.Width,
      Height = screenResolution.Height,
      WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
      ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
      Topmost = true,
      ShowInTaskbar = false,
      Background = Brushes.White,
    };
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100) };
    timer.Tick += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string t = TextMessage;
      if (text.Text != t)
        text.Text = t;
      if (IsStop)
      {
        timer.Stop();
        //Следующий код если не делать, то копится память, почему
        win.Hide();// win.Close(); то же самое
        win.Opacity = 1;
        win.Width = 1;
        win.Height = 1;
        win.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        win.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
        win.Topmost = false;
      }
    };
    win.Closing += delegate (object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Cancel = !IsStop;
    };
    timer.Start();
    win.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

И еще ниже тест программы

```
for (int i=0; i < 10;++i){
  WaitWindows ww = WaitWindows.Create();
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
  ww.Stop();
}
```

Comment: А если вместо этого всего кода просто `win.Close()`?

Comment: То же самое, это я эксперементировал

Comment: Отпишитесь от всех событий, когда они больше не нужны (закрытие окна, таймер).

Comment: kmv всё это сделано, таймер остановлен, на события не подписывался...